# RegEx Split on / Except when Surrounded by []

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to split a string in Java  on / but I need to ignore any instances where / is found between [].  For example if I have the following string

```
/foo/bar[donkey=King/Kong]/value
```

Then I would like to return the following in my output

- foo
- bar[donkey=King/Kong]
- value

I have seen a couple other similar posts, but I haven't found anything that fits exactly what I'm trying to do.  I've tried the String.split() method and as follows and have seen weird results:

```
Code:  value.split("/[^/*\\[.*/.*\\]]")

Result:  [, oo, ar[donkey=King, ong], alue]
```

What do I need to do in order to get back the following:

```
Desired Result:  [, foo, bar[donkey=King/Kong], value]
```

Thanks,
Jeremy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to split on the `/` followed by an *0 or more*  *balanced pairs* of brackets:

```
String str = "/foo/bar[donkey=King/Kong]/value";

String[] arr = str.split("/(?=([[^\\[\\]]*\\[[^\\[\\]]*\\])*[^\\[\\]]*$)");     
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

**Output:**

```
[, foo, bar[donkey=King/Kong], value]
```

**More User friendly explanation**

```
String[] arr = str.split("(?x)/"        +   // Split on `/`
                     "(?="              +   // Followed by
                     "  ("              +   // Start a capture group
                     "     [^\\[\\]]*"  +   // 0 or more non-[, ] character
                     "      \\["        +   // then a `[`
                     "     [^\\]\\[]*"  +   // 0 or more non-[, ] character
                     "     \\]"         +   // then a `]`
                     "  )*"             +   // 0 or more repetition of previous pattern
                     "  [^\\[\\]]*"     +   // 0 or more non-[, ] characters 
                     "$)");                 // till the end
```

Comment: Was a slight mistake in regex. Corrected now.

Comment: I need the / between the brackets to be kept.  In the solution provided the / goes away.  The solution provided does exactly the same thing as str.split("/") from what I've seen.

Comment: @jwmajors81. Sorry, the regex had a slight mistake. I corrected it now. You can test it again with the updated solution.

Comment: it has problem if the str has more `[../../..]` group. e.g. `"/foo/bar[donkey=King/Kong/kkk]/value/xy[aaa/bbb/cc]"` well if it is not the case OP needs, it is fine. good answer.

Comment: @Kent. Actually you are right. It does have problems. I'm surprised. Let me see how I can resolve this. BTW thanks :)

Comment: @RohitJain I gave it a try, I got output: `[, foo, bar[donkey=King, Kong, kkk], value, xy=[aaa/bbb/cc]]` donkey part seems have problem

Answer (score 0):

Of the following string, the regex below will match **foo** and **bar**, but not **fox** and **baz**, because they're followed by a close bracket.  Study up on negative lookahead.

```
fox]foo/bar/baz]
```

Regex:

```
\b(\w+)\b(?!])
```